# Get the value difference between two item.value from KeyValuePipe in Angular 6

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Was looking for a way to calculate the difference in value between two item.value from a nested JSON data object - positions.

My nested JSON data is as following

```
"campaign_performance": {
  "id": 11783,
  "name": "calvinseng.com",
  "mobile": "false",
  "date_from": "2018-01-01",
  "date_to": "2018-01-02",
  "keywords": [{
      "id": 235505,
      "name": "hot stamping printing",
      "positions": {
        "2018-01-01": 1,
        "2018-01-02": 1
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 235506,
      "name": "creative agency singapore",
      "positions": {
        "2018-01-01": 59,
        "2018-01-02": 57
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With the following ngFor I could list the item.value but not the difference between two keys which I plan to show after {{item.value}}

```
<ion-list color="primary" *ngFor="let keyword of userService.campaign_performance.keywords first as isFirst">
  <ion-list-header *ngIf="isFirst">
    <ion-label text-left>Keyword</ion-label>
    <ion-label text-right>Curt. Rank</ion-label>
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item>
    {{ keyword.name }}{{ userService.campaign_performance.campaign_status.rank_change }}
    <ion-label *ngFor="let item of keyword.positions | keyvalue; last as isLast" text-right>
      <span *ngIf="isLast">{{item.value}}</span>
    </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: what do you mean by difference? is it one value minus another?

Comment: yes. as there's only 2 keys. keyA- keyB

Comment: it's really not clear what you are trying to achieve mate, consider showing sample output please, thanks!

Comment: I have made a screenshot at https://prnt.sc/ofpbb8 Basically x-y for the value of z. and X and Y are the item.value from the mentioned JSON

Comment: so x->"2018-01-01" and y->"2018-01-02" ??

Comment: X is 1. Y is 1.

Comment: This is not a *template* problem. If there is *data* you need calculated, then calculate it before you pass the JSON object to the view. This is why we separate the template from the component. The component does the work and the template displays it.